# Get uncommon values from two or more arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any function in PHP which will give an array of uncommon values from two or more arrays?

For example:

```
$array1 = array( "green", "red", "blue");
$array2 = array( "green", "yellow", "red");
....
$result = Function_Needed($array1, $array2,...);
print_r($result);
```

Should give the output:

```
array("blue", "yellow", ...);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`array_diff`](http://php.net/array_diff) and [`array_merge`](http://php.net/array_merge):

```
$result = array_merge(array_diff($array1, $array2), array_diff($array2, $array1));
```

[Here's a demo.](http://codepad.org/1Cos2HiZ)

For multiple arrays, combine it with a callback and [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/array_reduce):

```
function unique(&$a, $b) {
    return $a ? array_merge(array_diff($a, $b), array_diff($b, $a)) : $b;
}

$arrays = array(
    array('green', 'red', 'blue'),
    array('green', 'yellow', 'red')
);

$result = array_reduce($arrays, 'unique');
```

[And here's a demo of that.](http://codepad.org/07yGJqT8)

Comment: @ShehzadBilal: Reduce; i.e., take `$array1` and `$array2` and perform this operation, then repeat for the result and `$array3`, and so on.

Comment: @ShehzadBilal you should have more appreciation for people who are going out of their way to help you, instead of rudely posting "incorrect" or "incomplete"

Comment: @ShehzadBilal: Here, I've added an example for *n* arrays. (And yes, please be a little more polite.)

Answer (score 2):

Try [`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php).​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2) + array_diff($array2, $array1);
```

Comment: You might want to call `array_values` on the result to bring the keys back to normal, by the way.

Comment: @ShehzadBilal C'mom ... Ever heard of `foreach`, or `for`? You should have mentioned in _the question_ ;)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. It can be extended to work with more than two arrays. It basically counts the common key occurrences and returns those with count of one:

```
$a = array('yellow', 'blue', 'red', 'green');
$b = array('blue', 'purple', 'green');

function unintersect($a, $b)
{
  $x = array_fill_keys($a, 1);
  foreach ($b as $v) {
    $x[$v]++; // this might trigger warning
  }
  return array_keys(array_filter($x, function($v) {
    return $v === 1;
  }));
}

print_r(unintersect($a, $b));
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => yellow
    [1] => red
    [2] => purple
)
```