# php compare strings return uncommon values?

Tags: php, mysql

I've found some great ways to return common values between php strings (via explode & array_intersect, etc.), but so far not much for returning the uncommon value.

I did find one question that addressed uncommon values, and [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371527/get-uncommon-values-from-two-or-more-arrays) used array_diff & array_merge. I had trouble making it look inside the actual values, to suit my needs.

I am working with a legacy database, with enough code built around it to make proper normalization a pipe dream, and would greatly appreciate any insight.

I have two columns in a mysql db table, a & b. Column a's data is duplicated in b, with a space separating them. I need to select/query/expose the non-duplicate data in b. There is a space between them, but it isn't the only one, which is driving me nuts because explode/implode won't cut it (or I don't know how to make it happen).

existing:

a Apples, Apples Blue, Apples Red Big

b
Apples Oranges, Apples Blue Bananas, Apples Red Big Ruby Red Grapefruit

I need:
Oranges, Bananas, Ruby Red Grapefruit

Any thoughts?

Comment: What specifically would you like? Everything I've tried has failed. Please have a look at the table field a and field b contents, and the desired output above.

Comment: @Daya, please stop linking to w3schools' PHP material.  It is out of date, full of bad practices and horrible security practices.  Instead, please link to the PHP manual.  In the case of string functions, that'd be [over here](http://php.net/ref.strings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I found a use of strstr() on php.net that did the trick (used below).
Link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php
Provided by: root at mantoru dot de

```
$needle = 'Apples Red Big';
$haystack = 'Apples Red Big Ruby Red Grapefruit';

function strstr_after($haystack, $needle, $case_insensitive = false) {
$strpos = ($case_insensitive) ? 'stripos' : 'strpos';
$pos = $strpos($haystack, $needle);
if (is_int($pos)) {
    return substr($haystack, $pos + strlen($needle));
}
// Most likely false or null
return $pos;
}

$goal = strstr_after($haystack, $needle);
echo $goal;
```

Returns: Ruby Red Grapefruit

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample column values and result above, I assume that you only need to compare value at the same index. **`Apples`** with **`Apples Oranges`**, **`Apples Blue`** with **`Apples Blue Bananas`**, and **`Apples Red Big`** with **`Apples Red Big Ruby Red Grapefruit`** since you don't expect output like **`Blue Bananas`** or **`Red Big Ruby Red Grapefruit`**.

So you may try something like this:

```
$non_duplicates = array();
foreach($columnA as $idx => $val) {
    $pos = strstr($columnB[$idx], $val);

    if($pos !== false)
        $non_duplicates[] = str_replace($val . " ", "", $columnB[$idx]);
}

var_dump($non_duplicates);
```

Comment: Hi SubRed, thank you very much for your suggestion, and your assumption about comparison is correct - per row. I'm trying to implement it and keep getting `code`array(0) { }`code`

Comment: Here's what I have, please point out my error(s): `code`$a = $row_TableA['a'];
$b = $row_TableA['b'];
$non_duplicates = array();
  foreach($a as $idx => $val) {
   $pos = strstr($b[$idx], $val);
  
   if($pos !== false)
    $non_duplicates[] = str_replace($val . " ", "", $b[$idx]);
  }
  
  var_dump($non_duplicates);`code`

Comment: Have you tried to `print_r` your `$a` and your `$b`? I don't see there is problem with the function, you should see these variable values first.

Comment: Sorry SubRed, maybe I just didn't understand the indexing. I found a use of strstr() on php.net that did what I needed.

Comment: No problem @Gary, the purpose is to get what you need to be done. Glad to hear you can manage it. It is better when you can solve it by yourself with your own understanding :)

Answer (score 0):

this should pretty much be what you looking for...

```
$a = 'Apples, Apples Blue, Apples Red Big';
$b = 'Apples Oranges, Apples Blue Bananas, Apples Red Big Ruby Red Grapefruit';

$diff = array_diff(toArray($b), toArray($a)); //diff between b and a
var_dump($diff);

function toArray($str){
  $str = trim(str_replace(array(',','  '), array('',' '), $str));  //clean string up
  return array_unique(explode(' ', $str));  //explode into array by spaces and make unique.
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

array(4) { [1]=> string(7) "Oranges" [4]=> string(7) "Bananas" [8]=> string(4) "Ruby" [10]=> string(10) "Grapefruit" }

Comment: Hi on_, I can't explode on spaces, since there are spaces in the desired result above. Am I missing something in your response?